# Rewrite url in htaccess to correct

Tags: .htaccess

I have link like this: `http://site.crm.int/project_discussions/test`

I need redirect it to : `http://site.crm.int/project_discussions/index.html?url=test`

Text 'test' is changable. Can be for example 'december', 'meetting01' etc.

I tried it in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^\/project_discussions/(.*)$ \/project_discussions\/index.html?url=%1 [L]
```

But have 404 error.

Also tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project_discussions/(.*) [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index\.html?url=$1 [L,NC]
```

And have **'Internal Server Error'**
How can i fix it? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for nice post, good that you shared your efforts, keep it up. Please confirm one thing do you want to change url in browser when you hit url http://site.crm.int/project_discussions/test NO right?

Comment: Yes, i need redirect to page site.crm.int/project_discussions/index.html?url=test

Comment: usually we don't show users ugly(php and query string containing) urls, so double checked :)

Comment: Yes, but it is old client site and all pages work like /domain/page.html?param=1. But for this page need that user will get nice link but when paste in browser will redirect to other link.

Comment: Sure, but fair warning you are showing users path of the files and servers, to hide them only htaccess is there. If its internal users and site then fine.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, please try following .htaccess rules file. Make sure .htaccess file and folder `project_discussions` are residing in same root folder. Also your index.php OR index.html file should be inside your project_discussions folder.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also I have fixed your previous rule for handling internal rewrites.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project_discussions/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/index.html?url=$2 [R=301,NE,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but have error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: And result is like this http://site/project_discussions/project_discussions/index.html?url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php&url=index.php

Comment: @IvanOlon, Do you have any other rules apart from these? OR any other htaccess files also?

Comment: Yes:  

'RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project_discussions/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/index.html?url=$2 [R=301,NE,QSA,L]

RewriteRule  ^((.*\.(html?|php))|((.+\/)?[^\.\/]*))$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]'

Comment: @IvanOlon, please post/edit ONLY your existing rules. And keep your current efforts/codes as it is, as its nice question/post as of now.

Comment: @IvanOlon, I have updated rules now. Please do check them once and let me know then how it goes.

Comment: Now also get error 'too many redicrects'. Maybe issue it with `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/index.html?url=$2 [R=301,NE,QSA,L]`

Comment: Now all my urls redicrect to /project_discussions/project_discussions/index.html?url=index.php&url=index.php&url=....

Comment: @IvanOlon, no its because of `RewriteRule ^((.*\.(html?|php))|((.+\/)?[^\.\/]*))$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,QSA,L]` as of now both are conflicting. So for which rewrite you have mentioned this please let me know and I will try to fix it then.

Comment: Ok, i am not sure what need write. All site pages are calling by folder structure. folder/page.html . But for 1 page need other rule.

Comment: @IvanOlon, ok can you please only keep my edited rules(without your rule) and then try urls and let me know which one working and which one not.

Comment: Ok, i used only your rules and when go to http://site/pd/test i see http://site.crm.int/pd/pd/index.html?url=test , must be one /pd

Comment: @IvanOlon, but you mentioned it like that and I double checked also you want it to redirected no in browser? Sorry I am confused now.